# How can we pass a single test method as parameter in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, testng

In my testng file i have

```
<test name="Tests" parallel="false">
    <classes>       
        <class name="packagename.TestPlanName">
        <methods>
        <include name="testMethod"></include>
        </methods>          
        </class>
    </classes> 
</test>
```

how can i pass testplanName and testcase name as parameters in Jenkins?
I use maven.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute entire class with all test methods you can use

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestPlanName
```

If you want to execute a particular test in the class

```
mvn test -Dtest=TestPlanName#testMethod
```

Comment: Hi Niharika, Thanks for the reply! I want to pass it as parameters in jenkins build.How should I modify my testng.xml file to accept testMethodname and testPlanName as parameter?